# cannot mix two audio files with amerge/amix ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm mixing two wav audio files as follows

```
/data/data/com.example.letsjam/app_bin/ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/test1.wav -i /storage/emulated/0/test2.wav -filter:v amerge=inputs=2 /storage/emulated/0/output.wav
```

The output wav file only has the sound of the first audio. Both audio files have same sample rate and same number of channels and of-course the same format i.e. wav. Here is the shell output of the command above:

```
shellLine: Input #0, wav, from '/storage/emulated/0/test1.wav':
shellLine:   Metadata:
shellLine:     encoder         : Lavf55.42.100
shellLine:   Duration: 00:00:05.02, bitrate: 2048 kb/s
shellLine:     Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 64000 Hz, stereo, s16, 2048 kb/s
shellLine: [wav @ 0x2d89340] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
shellLine: Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
shellLine: Input #1, wav, from '/storage/emulated/0/test2.wav':
shellLine:   Duration: 00:00:14.04, bitrate: 1024 kb/s
shellLine:     Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 64000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 2048 kb/s
shellLine: Output #0, wav, to '/storage/emulated/0/output.wav':
shellLine:   Metadata:
shellLine:     ISFT            : Lavf55.42.100
shellLine:     Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 64000 Hz, stereo, s16, 2048 kb/s
shellLine:     Metadata:
shellLine:       encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 pcm_s16le
shellLine: Stream mapping:
shellLine:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> pcm_s16le)
shellLine: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
shellLine: size=    1254kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=2048.2kbits/s    
shellLine: video:0kB audio:1254kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.007941%
```

Am i doing anything wrong? I also tried `amix` but got the same result. The generated output only has the sound of the first audio file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, providing the input files, if possible, would help us attempt to duplicate the issue.

Comment: Ok here are the input files:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4C18D0EDFD4D4F34!3895&authkey=!AIlYt6_InP_CyWw&ithint=folder%2cogg

I'm converting these audio files to wav with the following command
`/data/data/com.example.letsjam/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg -ar 64000 -ac 2 -vn /storage/emulated/0/test1.wav`
`

Comment: Here's the complete console output:
http://pastebin.com/QCz079m0

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `audacity`? You can have there multiple lines of audio synchronized, an then you can mix and export them. See [this manual entry](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/mixing.html).

Comment: I'm actually using ffmpeg binary in my android app. So I start a new process everytime I need to do anything related to audio from my android application and generate commands programatically.

Comment: @AbdulQadir Did you read [this example](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation#a2stereostereo)?